# Delphi 2006 bug in EOLN

Tags: windows, delphi, unix

I think there is a bug in the *EOLN* function in D2006 (WIN 32) when applied to text files with an Unix type of line break (*LF*), when this *LF* is the first character in the input buffer.
The source of the bug is the line

```
        TEST    [EDX].TTextRec.Mode,tfCRLF
```

which should correctly read

```
        TEST    [EDX].TTextRec.Flags,tfCRLF
```

It is the *Flags* field which stores the line brake style, not the *Mode* field, which stores the input/output mode.

Above line is part of the snippet below from the *Sytem* unit, which is called when the buffer needs to be refilled. The bug goes unnoticed because the *Mode* field is an odd number for input files (which is the mode where *EOLN* is usually used with)

```
fmInput  = $D7B1;
```

matching the only bit set in *tfCRLF* (=1) for Windows generated text files. Do newer versions of Delphi still have the same coding for *EOLN*?

```
function _Eoln(var t: TTextRec): Boolean;
asm
.
.
.
@@readChar:
        PUSH    EAX
        CALL    _ReadChar
        POP     EDX
        CMP     AH,cEOF
        JE      @@eof
        DEC     [EDX].TTextRec.BufPos
        XOR     ECX,ECX
        XCHG    ECX,EAX
        TEST    [EDX].TTextRec.Mode,tfCRLF
        JE      @@testLF
        CMP     CL,cCR
        JE      @@eol
        JMP     @@exit

@@eol:
@@eof:
        MOV     AL,1
@@exit:
end;
```

Another curiosity: this *EOLN* function, when applied to a Windows (*CRLF*) file type, actually does check only for the *CR*, as if it where an (old?) Mac file, no *LF* following is checked for!?

Comment: I think you are right. You should report this in QC. Best is to use the QC Windows Client as it is much easier to use than the web interface at http://qc.embarcadero.com

Comment: @Jeroen: Reporting it will only matter if it still exists in XE6. EMBT doesn't release patches to older versions once a newer one has been released, and D2006 is a very old version.

Comment: @Ken: QC isn't only for fixing bugs. It is also a repository for known issues in certain product versions. In addition those known issues can potentially used as regressions for newer versions.

Comment: @Jeroen: True. I didn't want to leave Marcelo with the impression that reporting it would result in a fix at some point for D2006, though. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite point taken. Will explain that in the future when suggesting QC for reporting bugs on older products.

Comment: @Jeroen & KenWhite: But what about the bug in those newer versions of Delphi, can one of you take a look at System.Eoln and tell me if it is still present? If yes, I will surely report it to EMBT.

Comment: @MarceloBergweiler if you provide a reproducible test case (preferably a [DUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUnit) based one as that testing framework has shipped with Delphi for a really long time), I can check.

Comment: @Jeroen: As we can not attach files here, I prepared a ZIP file and attached it to a new [EMBT report #124205](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124205)

Answer (score 0):

It was not <del>fixed</del> in 2007.

Here's the code from Delphi 2007

```
function _Eoln(var t: TTextRec): Boolean;
asm
  ....
  TEST    [EDX].TTextRec.Mode,tfCRLF <<-- incorrect reference still there
  JE      @@testLF
  CMP     CL,cCR
  JE      @@eol
  JMP     @@exit
@@eol:
@@eof:
      MOV     AL,1
@@exit:
end;
```

**Fixed in XE6**
In Delphi XE6 a pure Pascal version is used, which also correctly checks for t.Flags.
 **<sub>(Obviously otherwise it would not compile).</sub>**

I have not checked for any regressions in between.

Comment: Johan, the D2007 code is exactly the same as that in D2006. The bug is in the lower portion of your code, in that part beginning with "@@readChar". You will find the wrong reference to "Mode" there.

Comment: Bummer, anyway it's fixed in XE6.